# What are some of the maximal ideals in ℝ×ℂ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this, as my understanding would be to use (maximal ideal of R, maximal ideal of C) but not sure how to find these, I know for Z max ideals are mZ where m is prime but not really sure how to find max ideals for other uncoutable sets?

Comment: How do you define multiplication in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I think its just (ab,cd) with ab being x in R and cd being two elements in C multiplied